# Connect to github server

Tags: github, gitlab

I have the ip, useename and password of the github server, which uses gitlab, and I need to connect to it and manage files. What should I do?

Comment: What have you tried ? Did you look for documentation ?

Comment: I assume you mean GitHub-style server, and it is actually GitLab, not GitHub or GitHub Enterprise? And you mean programatically manage files, i.e. over an API that isn't the Git protocol? Here's documentation for GitLab's API if that's what you need? https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/

Comment: As Rup says, GitHub and GitLab are different things. Are you looking for a tutorial on Git or GitLab? Please see [ask] for tips on asking technical questions effectively. That's the best way to get good answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*I'm assuming you're asking how to manage/change files within a git repository. If you're asking something else, I've missed the point, apologies.*

Firstly you will need 'git' on your local machine - install it with your package manager or download and install it from the [git website](https://git-scm.com/).

Once git is installed you can **clone** a repository (which contains a set of files, and ends in .git) using the `git clone` command. Run `git clone --help` for more information on this, but if you already know the address of your git server and the path to the repository, it will look something like as follows:

```
git clone https://git-server.url/path/to/repo.git
```

Note that the URL you should use will depend on the configured transport protocol (git, ssh, http[s]) of your git server.

Next, you should makes some local configurations, for example, from a terminal:

```
git config user.name "your_username"
git config user.email "someone@example.com"
```

You can add `--global` to both of these command if you want these changes to persist outside of the current git repo.

Having a **cloned** repository automatically checks out an initial 'branch' on which you can make changes to files within your repository. See the [git docs](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v1/Git-Branching-What-a-Branch-Is) for a detailed explanation of a branch.

Files can be added, removed or renamed/moved using `git add`, `git rm` or `git mv` respectively.

Finally, you must **commit** your changes and **push** them

```
git commit -m "A message describing your changes"
```

`git remote` will confirm the name of the default remote (repo location). In this case, it is assumed to be `origin`. You can then push your changes to an existing branch (viewed using `git branch -r`), assumed to be `master` below:

```
git push origin master
```

Here you would be **merging** your master branch with the remote one. Clearly your permissions/project conventions will dictate what you can/should do to this repo.